# Excel - formula IF AND error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in my Excel spreadsheet, I want to identify the stores which have not spend and have Closed in front

```
OutletID    Name         Trans   Spend      Customers   
1234        Store1       61      $1,139.02  56
1235        ClosedStore2 0       0          0
```

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(SUM(C2:F2)=0,LEFT(B2,6)="Closed","DELETE"),"")
```

But doesn't seem to work as it returns `#VALUE!`

Can you please tell me where I've gone wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a missplaced bracket.

```
=IF(AND(SUM(C2:E2)=0,LEFT(B2,6)="Closed"),"DELETE","")
```